# Could not load directory in PHPUnit - как настроить в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpunit, php5

test in PHPStorm 2016.1.2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выполнение тестов выдаёт:

```
 /usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --configuration /home/makson/IDEA/php/PhpstormProjects/Server/application/autoloader/autoload.php /home/makson/IDEA/php/PhpstormProjects/Server/application/test
Testing started at 18:35 ...
Could not load "/home/makson/IDEA/php/PhpstormProjects/Server/application/autoloader/autoload.php".

ParsePI: PI php never end ...

Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Подскажите, что надо до настроить что бы нормально срабатывали тесты

Comment: Он вам ругается на файл. Смотрели, что в нем? Существует ли он?

Comment: @ Иван Пшеницын существует, знаю что в нем. самописный автолоадер для namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в моем случае была в том что я неправильно указал альтернативный конфигурационный файл, я указывал путь в автозагрузчик.
После создания `phpunit.xml` все работает норм.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="path/to/autoload.php"
colors="true">
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="Main">
  <directory>test</directory>
</testsuite>
```